# libGDX polygon rebound (bounce) angle

Tags: java, libgdx

I am hoping someone could point me in the direction of a libGDX example that shows how the rebound angle is calculated when a polygon hits another (which is fixed) - The questions/answers I've found on StackOverflow have all been to general (*abstract*), I'm hoping for a more libGDX specific answer :)

Currently, I am using `Intersector.MinimumTranslationVector` to check whether the moving polygon has hit another fixed-stationary polygon and then using the resultant values to shift the objects back out of each other.

When the collision occurs virtually or horizontally, the bounce calculation is easy and currently works well. What I am having troubles with are the diagonal collisions - working out which *face* was actually hit and the direction in which to bounce.

The moving polygon uses a `Vector2` object for it's velocity, so the question is how is the new velocity calculated? I'm assuming it can be done using the `Intersector` class, but how?